# How to speed up <img> append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm sorry if this is a novice question, but I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to Javascript...

So, here's the code snippet:

```
function insertSquares() {
    for (i = 0; i < 113; i++) {
        $('#wrapper').append('<span><img src="images/square_2.png" style='display: none;'/></span>');
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a loop that appends a `<span>` and an `<img>` to a `<div>` each time that the code is repeated. Normally, this appending isn't a problem, but since it has to do this a number of times in the loop, so it takes a while. (also, this function is called a number of times by a `setInterval()`, and it slows down the entire webpage)

When benchmarking this function with JSLitmus, it runs 5 ops/sec, and I would like to speed this up. I have already thought of using the loop to add the data to an array instead, (rather than appending each time through the loop) and then when outside of the loop, appending all of the data only once, but this does not seem to speed up the process by a noticeable amount.

So, is there some way I can speed this code up that I haven't thought of? I can't think of a more efficient way to load and display this amount of the same image.

Comment: For one, cache `$('#wrapper')` so jQuery doesn't have to find it each iteration.

Comment: So you append the same string 113 times?

Comment: That has a syntax error it.  You use single quotes for the string and for the style attribute without escaping them.  Not sure if this is your actual code or not though.

Comment: You may want to stop using jquery to parse your html and just create the elements via the dom.

Comment: @AlienWebguy - I didn't think to cache #wrapper, and it does help the speed, but only marginally. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Corbin - Oops, yes, that was a mistake I made when creating the question, it isn't in the actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing you can do is wait until you've finished the loop to make your changes to the DOM. Your current method will hammer the DOM into submission, and you certainly don't want this. Consider [Document Fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment) instead.

John Resig wrote about DOM Document Fragments some time back, but the post is still a good primer. You can find it online at http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/.

Comment: Hmm, this looks like a potential solution, but even with your links and a bit of research, I'm having a difficult time understanding it and integrating it into my code. It might take me a bit to grasp, I'll be back...

Comment: @Inconnu It will be well-worth your investment of time to grasp it. Essentially you create a container that you can push a load of elements onto. When you're all done, you insert *only* that container into the DOM. This keeps the browser from having to re-create portions of the DOM while you are cycling through your loop.

Comment: @Jonathon Sampson Well it looks like this is the best answer. I was able to modify my code a bit to be a functional example of what I need to do for the larger program, and it does complete the task faster. Timrwood's and vpiTriumph's suggestions were helpful as well, but for my purposes, document fragments seem best. It seems like images are my main problem. Any solution I use is slowed significantly when using images, but I don't think I'll be able to get a way around that.

Answer (score 5):

You could just work with strings until you need to append it.

```
function insertSquares() {
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 113; i++) {
        html += '<span><img src="images/square_2.png" style="display: none;"/></span>';
    }
    $('#wrapper').html(html);
}
```

Comment: This is the first thing I would try as well.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of this. I put your code through a benchmark test, but unfortunately in comparison to mine it didn't perform the task noticeably faster. I will try it in my larger scale program as well though, in case it will be faster under the larger workload than this smaller example.

Comment: There are many jsperf tests on this as well. http://jsperf.com/html-vs-append-jquery/2 http://jsperf.com/jquery-dom-create-array-string-append http://goo.gl/ZPxu3

Answer (score 0):

For smooth performance I agree with @jonathon-sampson and @timrwood that one modification to the DOM is preferable to many.

That said, the other way to boost your performance is to minimize the amount of html you are inserting into the DOM.  In your case I'd try to cut each element down to a single `<span>` block if possible using a CSS class to encapsulate common stylistic elements.

from:

```
html += '<span><img src="images/square_2.png" style="display: none;"/></span>';
```

to:

```
html += '<span class='myclass'></span>';
```

As a comment above noted, if you can avoid all of this in general and handle the creation of the DOM server side, that really would be the 'best' solution.

Comment: As they suggested, I'll certainly lower the modifications down to one. Unfortunately, I can't get rid of the image tag and use the span tags for that purpose, due to reasons not explained here, but you're right, the styling is completely unnecessary where it is. It's there because I'm currently just testing, and haven't yet moved the styling over to the external CSS... Oh, and if I knew how to implement a server-side DOM, I would, but web design is not my Forté.